# Spider Monkey dynamically created script (from JS), attached to an object

Tags: javascript, pdf, spidermonkey, xfa

I am working on an application that utilizes Spider Monkey to run our JS.  I only have a single object type (JSNode) that acts as an interface to a complex DOM consisting of various objects with properties and methods.  Everything is created and registered on the fly.  I am running into a problem where I have an object with a function that needs to be associated dynamically.  The problem is when I run the script from the context of the associated object, the NewResolve (which I usually use to recognize and define the properties), as far as I can tell cannot know it's a function definition to allow me to define the function on the fly.  I don't get the sense that JS_CompileScript will correctly build the function and associate it with the HandleObject.  And of course I can't utilize JS_CompileFunction without doing all of the script parsing myself, which to me feels like the point of utilizing spider monkey in the first place, but maybe I am wrong.

Any ideas or guidance on this issue?

Comment: Stackoverflow for spidermonkey is not active. Your best bet is the irc channel #jsapi on moz irc channels. Here is mibbit, an html5 client: https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23jsapi  Another place you can try is http://ask.mozilla.org/